# How to get a document from mongodb by using its string id and string collection name in SpringData

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I know that generally, we need to do something similar to this for getting a document back from mongodb in spring data:

1. Define a class and annotate it with @Document:

```
@Document ("persons")
public class Person
```

2. Use MongoTemplete:

`mongoOps.findById(p.getId(), Person.class);`

The problem is that in runtime I don't know the class type of the document, I just have its string collection name and its string Id. How is it possible to retrieve the document using SpringData? Something like this:

```
db.myCollectionName.findOne({_id: myId})
```

The result object type is not a concern, it can be even an object, I just want to map it to a jackson JsonNode.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround for this you can use the aggregate function of mongooperation like this

```
AggregationResults<Object> aggResults = mongoOps.aggregate(newAggregation(match(Criteria.where("_id").is(myId)) ,
                myCollectionName, Object.class);

    return aggResults.getUniqueMappedResult();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't solve my problem. I get a null value.